# WSO2 ESB Can't run Groovy script stored in registry

Tags: groovy, wso2, esb, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm trying to execute a Groovy script that I'm storing in the WSO2 ESB Local registry. When I do that I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned a NoSuchMethodException executing the external groovy script : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='file:Scripts/Groovy/test.groovy'} function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngine.mediate() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext) values: [org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext@716f8a10]
Possible solutions: wait()
```

If I put the code in-line in the script mediator, everything is running ok.
I've tried to wrap the script code like this `<x><![CDATA[...code...]]></x>`, as shown in the Using Ruby Scripts for Mediation example: 
[Sample 353: Using Ruby Scripts for Mediation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Sample+353%3A+Using+Ruby+Scripts+for+Mediation). I add the **groovy-all-2.4.7.jar** to **ESB_HOME\repository\components\lib** too.

How can I run the groovy scripts stored in the registry? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Groovy Script and the proxy, wiht which I'm testing:

Groovy Script

```
class Example {
   static def DisplayName() {
      println("This is how methods work in groovy");
      println("This is an example of a simple method");
   } 

   static void main(String[] args) {
      DisplayName();
   } 
}
```

Proxy service

```
<proxy name="TestScriptProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <script language="groovy"><![CDATA[println "This is an in-line script";]]></script>
      <script function="DisplayName"
        key="file:Scripts/Groovy/test.groovy" language="groovy"/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

ESB version is 5.0.0 running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Groovy script in the registry, the source should be the registry path. For example : `gov:scripts/Groovy/test.groovy`.

If you are referring a file give path relative to ESB_HOME. For example if scripts folder is in ESB_HOME directory, `file:scripts/Groovy/test.groovy`

First load the script file as below :

```
<localEntry key="DisplayNameScript" src="file:scripts/Groovy/test.groovy"/>
```

Now call the function

```
<script language="groovy" key="DisplayNameScript" function="DisplayName"/>
```